# CRM 2011 - IFRAME onChange event counter

Tags: iframe, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'd like to have a counter that will works on the OnChange event of the I_FRAME in CRM form
How could it be achieved?

thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain with more details your requirement?

Comment: @Guido Preite my I_FRAME provides a feature to add attachments (doc files), however, it's a SharePoint website. I'm thinking about how to count the number of files in such iframe an keep that nuber in a field